# A concept question about the divergence formula

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded subset, which is a manifold without boundary, we know for a general orientable manifold with boundary, we have :

$$\int_{M}(\operatorname{div} X) d V_{g}=\int_{\partial M}\langle X, N\rangle_{g} d V_{\widetilde{g}}$$

Where $\tilde{g}$ is an induced metric on the boundary $\partial M$.Since $M$ does no have boundary, it must be zero. correct? But this sounds not very reasonable? Since the integral of divergence is not always zero for an open subset unless the flux is zero?

Comment: The problem is, that the classical version of Stock's theorem (in differential geometry) holds only for vector field/ differential form that has compact support, if the vector field has **compact support** it must vanish on the boundary of the open subset, therefore it coinside with the divergence formula in calculus.  However in the calculus, we don't needs vector field has compact support on $U$ therefore it's a bit general than the classical version of stoke's theroem on the manifold in this context.

Comment: It seems to me that your comment above is an answer to your question.

Comment: Yeah , I just write it down, for the sake of memeory.And it's worthwhile maybe someone has the same confusion. I already have the answer before asking the question. @Didier